# Centre text in table and add color to cells

Tags: tables, color, multirow

Hi i'm trying to centre the text in the cell, there's on numbers so it's quite small, also i need to add color for the cells, (1 is green and 6 is red) but because I am using `\cline` it overwrites the lines.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,makecell,multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}

\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{#1}}}

 \begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l| >{\bfseries}p{2cm}|c|c|c|c|}
    \cline{3-6}
\mc{}
        &   \mc{Gravité du Dommage G1}
            &   \mc{Gravité du Dommage G2}                  \\
    \cline{3-6}
\mc{}
        &   \thead{Fréquence F1} & \thead{Fréquence F2}
            &   \thead{Fréquence F1} & \thead{Fréquence F2} \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{5}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O1}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3  \\
    \cline{2-6}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{5}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O2}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        &1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        & 1 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{5}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O3}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        & 1 & 2 & 3 & 5 \\
    \cline{2-6}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        & 1 & 2 & 4 & 6\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: And what are colors for other numbers (2, 3, 4 and 5)? Are they white?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution. I replaces `\line` with `\hhline` and I supposed you want to colour the *background* of some cells, not the numbers:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage[table, x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{makecell, hhline}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\renewcommand\theadalign{lc}
\newcommand\whitecell[1]{\cellcolor{white}{#1}}

    \begin{document}

\begin{table*}[!htbp]
  \centering\footnotesize
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
  \begin{tabular}{|l|l| *{2}{>{\columncolor{DarkSeaGreen3!75}}c|}c|c|}
    \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Gravité du Dommage G1}} & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Gravité du Dommage G2}}\\
    \cline{3-6}
    \multicolumn{2}{c|}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries Fréquence F1} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\bfseries Fréquence F2} & \textbf{Fréquence F1} & \textbf{Fréquence F2}\\
    \hline
   \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité \\ Occurrence O1}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}& 1 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
    \hhline{|~|*{5}{-|}}
                                   & \thead[lc]{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}& 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
    \hline
    \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité \\ Occurrence O2}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}& 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
    \hhline{|~|*{5}{-|}}
                                   & \thead{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}& 1 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
    \hline
    \multirowthead{3}{Probabilité \\ Occurrence O3}&\thead[lc]{Possibilité\\ Évitement P1}& 1 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
    \hhline{|~|*{5}{-|}}
                                   & \thead{Possibilité \\ Évitement P2}& 1 & \whitecell{2} & 4 & \cellcolor{Tomato1!90}{6} \\
    \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: actually I still get soething wrong, the lines are disappearing, mays I am using a package that overwriting

Comment: You're welcome. B.t.w., I've corrected some misspellings. Don't forget capital letters can have an accent in French.

Comment: Which lines disappear?

Comment: The vertical lines on each side of the 1st green column and 3 horizontal lines in the green column.

Comment: Are you sure this is not a problem with your pdf viewer? I don't have this phenomenon, as you can see from the image.

Comment: I use overleaf. So it's instantaneous. I'm trying to see if other packages used in the files are making this happen. Also, I'm french, but I mean I never put accent on capital letters lol

Comment: Well, that's bad typography, but it's your choice. By the way, I've corrected the code for the `\hhline`s (there were 3 small discontinuities in the leftmost vertical line). For the vertical lines that disappear in the first green column, you can play with the optional argument of `\columncolor` (the overlap of the colour) and set it to a value of, say, `[0.95\tabcolsep]` instead of the default `[\tabcolsep]`.

Comment: OK I think it's overleaf which is messing up, cause even with the code of the other solution the exact same lines are missing. I will try to find a way. Thanks

Comment: Oh where can I find a list of colors I can use to fill the cells, I like the ones you used :)

Comment: In `§4, Color by names`, of the documentation of `xcolor`. Most of the times, I use `x11names`, which has the widest palette. `svgnames` seems to be a simplified version of the former, and its names seem to be the same as HTML colours.

Comment: Yep I found it, thanks. Also you were right for some reason adobe doesn't display the lines correctly, but when I zoom they appear. I think it's a bug of Adobe. Cheers

Comment: If you're on Windows, it's better to use SumatraPDF: ultralight, ultra fast, supports direct and inverse search in TeX files.

Answer (score 2):

Temporary solution (until the desired colors  wouldn't be known):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array,makecell,multirow}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\normalfont\bfseries}

\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}% <-- needed for cell coloring


\usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{c|}{\thead{#1}}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\begin{tabular}{|>{\bfseries}l| 
                 >{\bfseries}m{25mm}|
                 >{\columncolor{green!30}}c|
                 >{\columncolor{green!30}}c|c|c|}
    \cline{3-6}
\mc{}
        &   \mc{Gravité du Dommage G1}
            &   \mc{Gravité du Dommage G2}          \\
    \hhline{~~|-|-|-|-|}
\mc{}
        &   \cellcolor{white}{\thead{Fréquence F1} }
            &   \cellcolor{white}{\thead{Fréquence F2}}
                &   \thead{Fréquence F1} 
                    &   \thead{Fréquence F2}        \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{3}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O1}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        & 1 & 1 & 2 & 3  \\
    \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|-|}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        & 1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{3}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O2}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        &1 & 1 & 2 & 4 \\
    \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|-|}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        & 1 & 1 & 3 & 5 \\
    \hline
\multirowcell{3}{Probabilité\\ Occurence O3}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P1
        &   1   &   \cellcolor{white}{2}
                    &   3   &   5 \\
    \hhline{~|-|-|-|-|-|}
    &   Possibilité Evitement P2
        &   1   &   \cellcolor{white}{2}
                    &   4 
                            &   \cellcolor{red}{6}\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
    \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

This MWE has problem with `\clines` in colored cells (known problem), I will manage this when I will know what are colors of other cells.

**Edit (1):** With help of package `hhline` are fixed `\cline` appearance in colored cells/columns. Instead of `\cline{2-6} is used`\hhline{~|-|-|-|-|-|}`.

If some colors are mising, they can be add on the similar way as it is done in colored cells/columns.

**Edit (2):** Regarding vertical position of numbers in cells beside solution provided in Bernard solution is another solution:

- instead `>{\bfseries}p{2cm}` use `>{\bfseries}m{25mm}`
- reduce number of lines, which span multirowcell, from 5 to 3

With this measures (now considered in above MWE) gives very similar result as it is present in Bernard answer.